# Stochastic pine script stratygy

Tags: pine-script, stochastic

Hi all hope ur doing well,

I’m trying to code a strategy that go long when k is in the overbought area and crossed d and the opposite for shorting

But I’m new to this and I don’t now how to write the long entry if the cross happen in the overbought area.

Thanks all,

Comment: check out this open source indicator link, this link contains a strategy for stochastic RSI , this may help you https://in.tradingview.com/script/22FnhBk9-Stochastic-RSI-Strategy/

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have coded the following to get strategy results that go long when k is in the overbought area and crossed d and the opposite for shorting.
More details added within the code comment.

```
//@version=5
strategy("Stochastic Strategy", overlay=true)
//Stochastic Inputs
length = input.int(14, minval=1)
OverBought = input(80)
OverSold = input(20)
smoothK = 3
smoothD = 3
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, length), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
//Rule to define crossover /crossunder
co = ta.crossover(k,d)
cu = ta.crossunder(k,d)

if (not na(k) and not na(d))
    //code to define if k is in overbought zone and k crossover d and enter a long trade
    if (co and k < OverSold)
        strategy.entry("StochLE", strategy.long, comment="StochLE")
    //code to define if k is in oversold zone and k crossunder d and enters a short trade
    if (cu and k > OverBought)
        strategy.entry("StochSE", strategy.short, comment="StochSE")
```